# Little Endian bytes confusion. How to obtain the integer value of 1 byte in little endian

Tags: objective-c

I have the following hex string:

`<0001cb01 1d006745 78568967 85001800 d7ff0000>`

I need to grab the third byte in little endian. What would the third byte look like in hex? What would be its decimal value?

```
<cb011d>
```

and

```
203
```

or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each byte is represented by two hex characters, ranging from 0x00 (0 decimal) to 0xFF (255 decimal) - the '0x' prefix is frequently used to denote hexadecimal. So your string represents 20 bytes, with values 0x00, 0x01, 0xCB, 0x01, etc.

To store numbers larger than 255 requires more than one byte - in little endian systems, the least significant byte comes first, and in big endian systems the most significant byte comes first. Little-endian numbers therefore appear 'backwards' in memory. The number 1000 decimal is 0x03E8 in hex, so on a little endian system the 0xE8 byte would appear first (at the lower memory address), followed by the 0x03 byte. A single byte is never 'little-endian' or 'big-endian' - that concept only applies to the ordering of multiple bytes.

It's not clear what your string is representing, though.  *Probably* you're supposed to assume that the string is a large number, and say which byte would appear in the third byte if this 20-byte number were stored little-endian, in which case it would be the third byte from the end, 0xFF, decimal value 255. Or it could mean the third byte in the string, 0xCB, decimal 203. You'll have to decide that based on what else you know about the problem.